# Ons-split-view and ons-sliding-menu in the same app

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ipad, onsen-ui

I'd like to develop a mobile application that behave different in landscape and portrait mode.

In portrait (and or on small devices, like iPhone) I want to use the ons-sliding-menu component.
In landscape in big screens (eg: iPad in landscape) I would like to have the ons-split-view.

Is it possible to do that? How can I handle the two resolutions?
Thank you.

Comment: There's an entire page dedicated to this topic on the Android developer site: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Hi @Karakuri, than you for your answer, but this doesn't help me with the Onsen UI framework!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ons-split-view does exactly like that and it works on all devices, only depends on orientation as:

In portrait, it'll act as ons-sliding-menu, where you slide to show the menu.

In landscape, it'll be a split view

Answer (score 0):

ons-split-view open/close function is deprecated and will be deleted from 1.2 version, try to use [ons-if-orientation](http://onsen.io/guide/components.html#ons-if-orientation) to switch between ons-split-view and ons-sliding-menu, that should be work, another option is to use ng-if.